Pyqt5 drag object but appeare wrong place
I have drag and drop algorithm on this screen but I have little problem in this code when I drag first movement, box appears wrong place. How can I solve this problem?
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QPainter, QPen, QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from test import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRect, QPoint





class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.boxes = []  # Klonlanmış box'ların listesi

        self.original_box = QPixmap("box.png").scaled(100, 150)  # Orjinal box resmi
        self.original_palette = QPixmap("palette.png")
        # print( self.img.width(),self.img.height())
        self.ui.image.setPixmap(self.original_box)
        self.ui.palet.setPixmap(self.original_palette)

        self.dragging = False  # Sürükleme durumu
        self.offset = None  # Sürükleme konumu
        self.ui.image.setFixedSize(self.original_box.width(), self.original_box.height())
        self.ui.palet.setFixedSize(self.original_palette.width(), self.original_palette.height())
        # self.ui.image.setScaledContents(True)
        self.ui.image.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.ui.image.setStyleSheet("QLabel { padding: 0px; }")

        # self.ui.palet.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        # self.ui.palet.setStyleSheet("QLabel { padding: 0px; }")
        print("After")
        self.ui.widget_2.setAcceptDrops(True)  # Bırakma işlemini kabul et
        self.firstMove = False



        self.last_offset = None
    def paintEvent(self, event):


        self.ui.palet.setPixmap(self.original_palette)

        painter = QPainter(self.ui.palet.pixmap())

        if self.dragging :
            # self.ui.palet.setPixmap(self.original_palette)

            painter.drawPixmap(int(self.offset.x() - self.original_box.width() / 2),
                               int(self.offset.y() - self.original_box.height() / 2),
                               self.original_box)

        for box in self.boxes:
            painter.drawPixmap(box.topLeft(), self.original_box)



    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            print(event.pos())
            # print("MAUSE GLOBAL POS",self.ui.image.mapFromGlobal(event.globalPos()))
            # print(self.ui.image.rect().contains(self.ui.image.mapFromGlobal(event.globalPos())))
            if(self.ui.image.rect().contains(self.ui.image.mapFromGlobal(event.globalPos()))):
                self.dragging = True
                self.offset = event.pos()
                self.firstMove = True
                print("Offset point", self.offset)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.dragging:
            # print("DRAGGING")
            print(self.ui.image.mapFromGlobal(event.globalPos()))
            # Sürüklenen box'ın merkezini güncelle
            self.offset = event.pos()
            self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and self.dragging:
            self.dragging = False

            print("RELEASE")
            self.relase = True
            # Yeni box'ı oluştur
            new_box = QRect(int(self.offset.x() - self.original_box.width() / 2),
                            int(self.offset.y() - self.original_box.height() / 2),
                            self.original_box.width(), self.original_box.height())
            # self.ui.palet.setPixmap(self.original_palette)
            # self.ui.palet.show()

            self.boxes.append(new_box)
            self.update()
            self.boxes[-1].moveCenter(self.offset)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)


    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

I can drag and drop into this palet image:

But I have little problem here, when I click the box it detects but this create on here:

I think I have problem with event.pos() how can I solve this ?

This is one of the many problems caused by managing events (mouse and paint) in the main window instead of delegating proper widgets for it. As said, you should consider the QGraphicsView framework instead. Don't try to immediately port your code to that, though: take your time to learn about its basic aspects, and when you do understand them, gradually apply what you learnt to your needs.
